# Change gameobjects position if it's already used by a different gameobject?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, position, gameobject

Gameobjects are getting randomly spawned on some platform objects. I want to avoid these two different gameobject to be spawned at the same exact location (money2 should change it's position).

Here is the code:

```
void Start()
{
    int randMoney = Random.Range(0, 8);
    Vector3 moneyPos = transform.position;
    moneyPos.y += 0.5f;
    if (randMoney < 1)
    {
        GameObject moneyInstance = Instantiate(money, moneyPos, money.transform.rotation);
        moneyInstance.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    }

    int randMoney2 = Random.Range(0, 8);
    Vector3 money2Pos = transform.position;
    money2Pos.y += 0.5f;
    if (randMoney2 < 1)
    {
        GameObject money2Instance = Instantiate(money2, money2Pos, money2.transform.rotation);
        money2Instance.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    }

    if (money2Pos == moneyPos)
    {
        //where gameobject2s position should change
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: Check if the position is the same/too close and keep picking a new random position until you found a free one?

Comment: Oh I think now I got it .. well simply check if the first coin was already spawned and then skip the second part .. I think that is what you are asking right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do the same thing multiple times here. First the code block for money1 and money2 are similar if not exactly the same. Consider creating a function like this one:

```cs
public GameObject SpawnMoney(GameObject moneyPrefab, int spawnProbability, Vector3 spawnOffset)
{
    int spawnPourcentage = Random.Range(0, 101); // 101 because the random is exclusive
    bool willSpawn = spawnPourcentage <= spawnProbability;
    //if not supposed to spawn, then do nothing
    if(!willSpawn) return null;

    //Spawn effectively the money with position offset
    Vector3 plateformePosition = transform.position;
    GameObject moneyInstance = Instantiate(moneyPrefab, plateformePosition + spawnOffset, Quaternion.identity, transform);

    //return the instance if you want to manipulate it later ;)
    return moneyInstance;
}
```

Now you have your function ready to go, you may spawn your coins in a start or even in a loop if you want to !

If you have questions, please ask